# On an exact expression for the squares of the distances of the critical points to a given zero of a polynomial

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Let $p(z) = \prod_{j=1}^{l+1} (z - z_j)^{M_j}$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n$, where the $z_j$ are distinct for $1, \ldots, l+1$. The first $l$ entries in the list $\{z'_1, \ldots, z'_{n-1} \}$ of the not necessarily distinct critical points, $(p'(z'_k) = 0)$, shall be of the second kind, hence $p(z'_k) \neq 0$, while the rest will be of the first kind, $p(z'_k) = 0$.

Consciously deviating slightly from
"Borcea’s variance conjectures on the critical points of polynomials" by D. Khavinson, R.Pereira, M. Putinar, E. Saff and S. Shimorin in Notions of Positivity and the Geometry of Polynomials, Series: Trends in Mathematics, Birkhäuser, Basel, 2011, pp. 283 – 309, https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5167,
we define the augmented Gauss-Lucas-matrix $D_{ps}$ by

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{D_{ps}}  \ := \ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 - C_1           &        \ldots        &        1 - C_{l+1}                 \\
d_{11} & \ldots         &         
d_{1(l+1)}         \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
d_{l1}        &       \ldots         &         
d_{l(l+1)}        \\
\end{pmatrix} \, ,
\end{equation}
where $$ d_{kj} := \frac{M_j}{n} \frac{H(z'_k)}{|z_j - z'_k|^2} \, , \qquad H(z'_k) \ := \ \frac{n}{\sum^{l+1}_{t=1} \frac{M_t}{|z_t - z'_k|^2}} \, , \qquad C_j := \sum_{k=1}^l d_{kj} .
$$
We will also more generally need
$$
H(x) \ := \ \frac{n}{\sum^{l+1}_{t=1} \frac{M_t}{|z_t - x|^2}} \, , \qquad A(x) \ := \ \sum^{l+1}_{t=1} \frac{M_t |z_t - x|^2}{n}
$$
to discuss additional properties.
The definition implies all row and column sums of $D_{ps}$ to equal 1, so it is a positive doubly stochastic matrix, if the answer to the following **question** is affirmative:

Is $C_j < 1$ true for each $j \in \{ 1 , \ldots, l+1 \}$ of every complex polynomial $p(z)$ which has at least two distinct zeros?

This is an addition at the end of my old question [The Poisson-kernel in the plane and polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/q/153105/37855), but it is of a different nature, I have a lot of additional info and even though there was recent progress on related questions, [Sendov's conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/360035/37855), and there are more recent claims to have settled Sendov`s conjecture, https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.00348 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.08720, the augmented Gauss-Lucas-matrices are of independent interest.

**More background/related results:**

1. **Connection to Sendov's conjecture, Borcea's variance conjecture:**
   From $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{z_j}{z_j - z'_k} = n$ one derives by an elementary, simple calculation
   $$
   D_{ps}(|z_1|^2, \ldots, |z_{l+1}|^2)^t = (\star, H(z'_1) + |z'_1|^2, \ldots, H(z'_l) + |z'_l|^2)^t \, ( \mathrm{I}) \, .
   $$
   As the entries of $D_{ps}$ are invariant with respect to translations in the complex plane of the zeros of $p(z)$, this implies
   $$D_{ps}(|z_1 - c|^2, \ldots, |z_{l+1} - c|^2)^t = (\star, H(z'_1) + |z'_1 - c|^2, \ldots, H(z'_l) + |z'_l - c|^2)^t \, ( \mathrm{II}) $$
   for an arbitrary complex $c$. Putting $c = z_i$ and summing over $k$ excluding the first row, we obtain
   $$ \sum_{j=1}^{l+1} \frac{C_j}{l} |z_j - z_i|^2 =  \frac{1}{l} \sum_{k=1}^l (H(z'_k) + |z_i - z'_k|^2) \, . $$
   We note the convex combination of the $|z_j - z_i|^2$ on the left and that equation $(\mathrm{I})$ implies $ H(z'_k) \leq 1$ for each $z'_k$, if $|z_j| \leq 1$ for all $j$, where equality occurs if and only if $p(z) = z^n - d$ and $|d| = 1$.
   Independently from this, proceeding as in part 6 of the cited article by Khavinson et al., we get
   $$ \sum_{j=1}^{l+1} |z_j - z_i|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} |z_j - S|^2 + n|z_i - S|^2 - \sum_{k=l+1}^{n-1} |z'_k - z_i|^2 \, , $$
   where $S$ is the centroid of the zeros $z_j$, using the relation between zeros and critical points of the first kind. Now comes the catch of our definition of $D_{ps}$: As all row and column sums of $D_{ps}$ equal 1, it preserves the component sum of each vector it is multiplied to, so without further effort, we obtain the equation
   $$ \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} ( H(z'_k) + |z_i - z'_k|^2) + r_{1i} = n|z_i - S|^2 + \sum_{j=1}^{n}|z_j - S|^2 \, (\mathrm{III}) \, , $$
   in general, where $$r_{1i} = \sum_{j=1}^{l+1} (1-C_j)|z_j - z_i|^2 $$
   and $H(z'_k) = 0$ for the critical points $z'_k$ of the first kind, corresponding neatly to the usual convention for harmonic mean values. This gives a general exact expression for the arithmetic  mean of the squares of the distances of the critical points to a given zero of an arbitrary complex polynomial with at least two distinct zeros and an affirmative answer to our question above results in a sufficient though not necessary condition for $r_{1i}$ to be strictly positive, implying
   $$\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} |z_i - z'_k|^2 <  \frac{n}{n-1} |z_i - S|^2 + \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|z_j - S|^2 - \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} H(z'_k) \, (\mathrm{IV}) $$
   for every $z_i$, no matter the multiplicities of the zeros.  One may do more without much effort: Multiplying $(\mathrm{II})$ by $M_i$ and summing over $i$, we obtain
   $$
   D_{ps}(A(z_1), \ldots, A(z_{l+1}))^t = (\star, H(z'_1) + A(z'_1), \ldots, H(z'_l) + A(z'_l))^t \, (\mathrm{V}) \, ,
   $$
   so the sum of harmonic and arithmetic mean values of the squared distances of a critical point to the zeros is expressed as the same convex combination as used in a classical proof of the Gauss-Lucas-Theorem, but now using the arithmetic mean values of a single zero to all zeros, bounding $H(z'_k)$ from above and $A(z'_k)$ from below at the same time by one half of it.
   Furthermore, one may combine
   $$
   \frac{1}{z_j - z'_k}\frac{1}{\overline{z_i} - \overline{z'_k}} + \frac{1}{z_i - z'_k}\frac{1}{\overline{z_j} - \overline{z'_k}} \ = \ \frac{1}{|z_j - z'_k|^2} + \frac{1}{|z_i - z'_k|^2} - \frac{|z_j - z_i|^2}{|z_i - z'_k|^2|z_j - z'_k|^2}
   $$
   and
   $$
   \frac{M_i^2}{|z_i - z'_k|^2} \ = \ \left( \sum_{j=1;\\ j \neq i}^{l+1} \frac{M_j}{z_j - z'_k} \right) \left( \sum_{j=1;\\ j \neq i}^{l+1} \frac{M_j}{\overline{z_j} - \overline{z'_k}} \right)
   $$
   to obtain
   $$
   d_{ki} \ = \ \frac{n - M_i}{n} \, - \, \left( \sum_{1 \leq r < s \leq l+1; \\ r,s \neq i} d_{kr}d_{ks} \frac{|z_r - z_s|^2}{H(z'_k)} \right) \, ,
   $$
   which implies statement 4. below and
   $$
   H(z'_k) \ = \ \sum_{1 \leq r < s \leq l+1} d_{kr}d_{ks} |z_r - z_s|^2 \, ,
   $$
   which can be combined with $(\mathrm{II})$ to get the I think quite remarkable equality
   $$
   \left( \frac{|z_i - z'_k|}{1 - d_{ki}} \right)^2 \ = \ \sum_{j = 1; \\ j \neq i}^{l+1} \frac{d_{kj}}{1 - d_{ki}} |z_j - z_i|^2 - \sum_{1 \leq r < s \leq l+1; \\ r,s \neq i} \frac{d_{kr}}{1 - d_{ki}} \frac{d_{ks}}{1 - d_{ki}} |z_r - z_s|^2 \, ,
   $$
   where convex combinations are at work again. Compare statements 4. and 5. below.
2. If $D_{ps}$ is doubly stochastic, it gives a direct approach to the majorization of the critical points and the centroid by the zeros, which was used by Pereira and independently Malamud to settle a number of open problems in the early 2000s.
3. $C_j = \frac{n - M_j}{n}$ if all zeros are on a straight line, see the cited article, or on a circle, see my old question.
4. Using $p'(z'_k)/p(z'_k) = 0$ and the inequality for the arithmetic mean and the root mean square, I have also proven
   $$d_{kj} \leq \frac{n - M_j}{n} \, ,$$
   where equality occurs if and only if there are exactly two distinct zeros.
5. There is no other reasonable inequality for a single $d_{kj}$, but the $C_j$ seem to be bounded from below about as tightly as they are from above.
6. Let all zeros be of the same multiplicity, then the perpendicular bisector theorem in polynomial geometry implies the existence of a row $k$, where $d_{ki} \geq d_{kj}$, if a fixed column $i$ is compared to any single column $j$, but the row $k$ cannot always be chosen to be the same for all columns $j$. Apart from this result, I have only empirical knowledge of the entries of $D_{ps}$ in general. Looking at $(\mathrm{II})$, one can investigate results related to the perpendicular bisector theorem by mapping suitable vectors with $D_{ps}$.
7. Examples of the type $p(z) = (z^n - 1)(z - \gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is a complex number of small absolute value illustrate the points 4, 5 and 6.
8. The question about the $C_j$ has been checked for a number of parametric families of polynomials of low degree and some random configurations of low degree by my pupils and me, the answer has always been affirmative up to now, the usual symmetric extremal configurations $p(z) = z^n - 1$ and $z^n - z$ also fit in nicely.
9. For large degree $n$, the bounds get arbitrarily tight and counterexamples may well exist.
10. If $(A(z_1) - \frac{1}{l+1} \sum_{j=1}^{l+1} A(z_j), \ldots, A(z_{l+1}) - \frac{1}{l+1} \sum_{j=1}^{l+1} A(z_j))^t$ is not the zero vector, it is an eigenvector of $D_{ps}^tD_{ps}$ for some rather symmetric configurations of the zeros of low degree.
11. At least some $D_{ps}^tD_{ps}$ and $D_{ps}D_{ps}^t$ are related to number theoretic questions like congruent numbers.